# Why build fails to compile and does not recognize __OBJC__ macro in *pch?

Tags: ios, objective-c

We store header files of shared components inside *.pch file, inside __ OBJC__:

```
#ifdef __OBJC__
  #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
  #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
  #import "Constants.h"
  // other headers goes there
#endif
```

I know this macro is used to tell compiler these classes require objc to run but sometimes very weird issue happens - __ OBJC__ is not recognized and so whole app does not see these shared headers and so a ton of error appear. But I ran out of imagination how this could happen. Sometimes the issue goes away by commenting out ifdef __ OBJC__, building, then uncommenting and building (magic). But sometimes it takes longer - I was pulling my hairs yesterday whole evening, but today it's working again. Closing and opening Xcode didn't helped, cleaning build and deleting DerivedData also. I'm using most recent Xcode version (5.0.2), project "Architectures" are set to "Standard architectures (including 64 bit)". Wish to know why it's happening so.

Comment: Since my projects are all Objective-C, I get rid of the #ifdef block and just list the headers.

Answer (score 1):

Do all your files end in .m? Or are some .c or .cc?

Comment: All files have *.m extension.